# How to replicate a wordpress site in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, themes

I want to build a personal website on wordpress.com

I have found a website that I really like the look of and want my website to look extremely similar to that website, maybe with just different assets.

I have some experience in Java and C but none in html. What would be the best way to replicate the source website onto my own website. I know I can inspect the element and look at the source code but it is really unintuitive. Is there a better way? How do I find the themes the original site used? Is there any way to copy the html code onto my own website?

Comment: Question doesn't fit in with the format of this site since it essentially amounts to "How do I steal a website?".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to build it on WordPress.com? It's hosted by WordPress, but also very limited and you can't really modify the themes.

If you want more control, you should do it using self-hosted WordPress.org package.

To check what kind of theme is used, go to source code and search for "wp-content/themes/theme-name" or find the main CSS file (often style.css) as there will be commented details that are shown by WordPress in Themes menu.

There are 2 options:

1. The website you like is a custom design and there is no easy way to copy that and it can be even illegal if you don't ask the owner. If you really want to copy the source, there is only a manual way - you download the source styles and scripts and modify it. Tough and risky way, because the sources are often minified.
2. The website is using a free or premium theme, available to buy, that's going to save you hours of work and probably allows a lot of customization, so you only have to spend some time to adjust it to your needs, upload photos etc. You will probably even don't have to look at the code.
3. (extra) If you still don't know what theme it is - ask the owner

Comment: Is there any way to find out if it's one or two?

Comment: Edited the answer. You can also find the main CSS file (often style.css) and look at the comments on top of it